# Flagged a spammy answer, answer vanished but I did not get 'helpful'?

Tags: support

I flagged a spam answer from the user [Caleb Bahler](https://serverfault.com/users/104463/caleb-bahler) in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/246214/can-i-hook-a-firewall-inside-a-network-and-vpn-connect-to-another-network), but did not get the helpful flag (and presumably no flag weight either).

The answer is gone - does that mean that someone else flagged it before me and got the points? Do I loose flag weight because of this, or is it only negative when you get a flag decline?

I'm perhaps a bit anal about this, but I like to see "helpful" on every single flag :)

Edit: Per request - here is a screenshot of the relevant flag history. The one I'm asking about is the one marked in the middle as spam.

[image]

Comment: What's it show in your flag history?  AFAIK, "spam" flags get no weight..

Comment: @ShaneMadden question updated

Comment: Huh.. well, I thought they didn't, but looking in my history now, all of my spam flags do now say `Helpful` (in strange contrast to other flags' lowercase `helpful`).  Recent UI change?

Comment: Probably a minor typo bug

Comment: I'm sure spam flags have only recently started to accrue FW - perhaps it's been removed again.

Comment: FWIW, I have a number of flags which were not marked rejected, helpful or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this is very strange. Normally if a moderator deletes a post, the flag gets automatically   *accepted* and considered *helpful*.

The only (unlikely) way that this could happen is that one moderator declines and another deletes the post. I'll look into this, but I'm pretty sure this didn't happen yesterday.

I'll update this answer as soon as I have any new details.

Comment: Yeah really. The flag history shows a normal work-flow. No idea why the existing flag didn't get 'helpful'.

Comment: Its possible that the post got 6 spam flags and was auto-deleted, in which case I don't think any weight gets added...

Comment: @MarkHenderson the post was deleted by sysadmin1138

Answer (score 1):

Its only negative if you get the DECLINED.

Can't say what happened there, but you probably should have got a HELPFUL...

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that just deleting the post doesn't validate the flag. A moderator needs to flag as spam themselves to mark the flag as helpful. If they delete the post instead of flagging the spam flags are neither invalidated nor marked helpful.

There is no feedback from the mod interface about this stuff, so I might be wrong about this.